# How to convert angular js filter into function call

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a function, that takes 2 numbers, and does stuff to it. I've tested it without angularJS and works as expected.

Is there a way to convert an angularJS filtering expression, into a function of the form:

```
{{a, b | function}}
```

which returns
     `function(a,b)`?

Comment: Why dont you use it {{function(a,b)}} which returns the desired output . I first thought of that way . And checking out https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter  is helpful for you .

Comment: Can you explain why do you want to return a function? If you are using angular filter, you are intending to filter some data to desire data. Do you just want to make a filter as a function call by passing two variables and return you the data based on the variable you passed?

Comment: @ShaohaoLin I believe that you've explained exactly what I want to do. The function in question loads specific nodes from and XML file, based on the variables provided `function(1,2)` returns the NodeValue of the 2nd child of the first node and so forth.

I wanted to see if there would be an easy way for me to just get the info onto the webpage without having to type a new script for every value and then just slap that data where I want it.

so not this:

`$('#id').append("function(a,b)");`

or anything larger than that.
just,

`{{ a, b | filter }}`

Comment: So `a` and `b` are some arbitrary variable? What's the reference that you  said first node? I mean the first node of what (start point)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

HTML:

```
<a>{{getValue(a,b)}}</a>
```

JS:

```
$scope.a =1;
$scope.b = 2;
$scope.getValue= function(a,b){
 return a+b;// do whatever your condition require
}
```

OR:::

HTML:

```
<a>{{ a | filter: filterFunction}} </a>
```

JS:

```
$scope.a = 1;

    $scope.filterFunction = function(element) {
      return element + 2 // will return 3
    };
```

Comment: I think this idea covers everything that I have been hoping for...
I think. It looks like, as I was working, my xml-reading function broke... I seriously can't figure out what's wrong with that... I mean, it just worked earlier...